# What medieval fantasy novel features a firey red head female protagonist with medical skills?

Tags: story-identification

I read this book about 7 years ago, and all I can remember of the title is that it had "Fire" in it, or something similar.

It featured a young woman with bright red hair who was a commoner and was learning about medicinal techniques.  She ended up going on a war campaign and struggling through being an intelligent woman in the medieval times when nobody respected her opinion.

This was the first novel in a series, and it came out around 2004, it was still in hard cover and none of the others had been released at the time.  It was also a first novel for the author, and she was not well known.

Can you guys help me remember what this novel was called?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question isn't actually that specific — fantasy with female heroines is quite *en vogue* at the moment. Nonetheless…

Could this be [*Firethorn*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firethorn_%28novel%29) by [Sarah Micklem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Micklem)? It is indeed [her first novel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Sarah_Micklem), [published in 2004](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?155478) [in hardcover](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?FRTHRN2004), and there is now a [second novel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?870625) [in that series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?27935). The heroine is a young red-haired commoner woman, and she does get to live through a war campaign. However, the Wikipedia summary mentions a magical gift rather than medical training.

I haven't read that book; I found it by browsing the [ISFDB search results](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/search.cgi) with title=fire and year=2004 and type=novel. If that's not the right book, maybe a name in the search results will jog your memory.

Comment: this is it, thanks! Now that you mention it I think there was some magical, but I think for medical purposes. Really great book, highly recommended and I'm going to have to pick up that second novel now.

Comment: i just re-read firethorn, and it's not exactly magic, more like green lore / witch craft.  I also read wild fire, the second book and was disappointed to find it end in a cliff hanger with no mention of when the third book might be appearing (though not disappointed with the novel). she seems to like to take her time with these ;)